# Still a novice could use a little help

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Ok, so I have this question, and we never went over this or how to solve it in class. I can't find an example in the book either.

How do I show that $f_n = 3^nA + 2^nB$ satisfies the recurrence equation $f_n = 5f_{n-1} - 6f_{n-2}$ for $n\geq2$?

What exactly is $A$ and $B$, and how do I even get started? What would be the first thing I look for? (If this is a calculus type problem, keep in mind that my highest math attained so far is trig, so sorry for being ignorant, just haven't seen this type of problem in book, power point, notes, or lecture).

Comment: @jack im pretty sure he wanted the -1 and -2 inside the parenthesis, since it's a recurrence

Comment: actually x isn't a variable, it's multiplicaion... sorry And its 5f sub n-1 minus 6f sub n-2

Comment: @jack that's probably A \times 3^n and so on

Comment: Please learn to use LaTeX (math typesetting) for future questions. To learn how, you can hit the "edit" button under your question and see the code used. You can also right-click on any formula you see here and click on "Show Math As $\to$ TeX commands" to see how it was coded.

Comment: Ah ok. Sorry, Thanks!!!!

Comment: @AntonioMontana As for your question, do you understand all the definitions involved? In other words, do you at least know what it means to "satisfy a recurrence equation" ?

Comment: Not really? Care to explain. Sorry if I'm slow

Comment: @AntonioMontana Are you self studying? Where did you come across this problem exactly? If you haven't done calculus yet, I can't imagine they would have given you this problem in school. Not that you need calculus for this, it's just that normally this kind of thing is done after calculus.

Comment: This is discrete math, but so many of the subjects in this book is beyond me. I paid 35 dollars an hour for a tutor but it's too ridiculous so came here to see if I could learn some. Not self studying, but I don't have Calculus till next semester.

Answer (score 2):

substituting we get:  $$5f_{n-1}-6f_{n-2}=$$

$$5(A*3^{n-1}+B*2^{n-1})-6(A*3^{n-2}+B*2^{n-2})=$$

$$5A*3^{n-1}+5B*2^{n-1}-6A*3^{n-2}-6B*2^{n-2}=$$

$$5A*3^{n-1}+5B*2^{n-1}-2A*3^{n-1}-3B*2^{n-1}=$$

$$ 3A*3^{n-1}+2B*2^{n-1}=A*3^n + B*2^n$$

In conclusion all you had to do was substitute and use laws of exponents.

In general whenever you have to prove a recurrence relation you should just evaluate for $f_n$, and then evaluate the thing they are telling you it should be equal too. If they are the same then it holds. Hope this helps.

Regards.

Comment: ok let me see if i can figure it out. I don't quite understand the exponent part though

Comment: $6$ is $3*2$ and $2*2^{n-1}$ is just $2^n$

Comment: Oh crap, got it!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like $A$ and $B$ are supposed to be numbers.  Depending on your choice of $A$ and $B$, you define a different sequence $\{f_1,f_2,\dots\}$, but every such sequence should satisfy the recurrence equation.

We verify that the recurrence relation is satisfied as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
5f_{n-1} - 6f_{n-2} &=
5(3^{n-1}A + 2^{n-1}B) - 6(3^{n-2}A + 2^{n-2}B) \\
&= (5)3^{n-1}A + (5)2^{n-1}B - (6)3^{n-2}A - (6)2^{n-2}B)\\
&= [(5)3^{n-1} - (6)3^{n-2}]A + [(5)2^{n-1} - (6)2^{n-2}]B\\
&= [(5)(3) - (6)]3^{n-2}A + [(5)(2) - 6]2^{n-2}B\\
&= (9)3^{n-2}A + (4)2^{n-2}B \\
&= 3^nA + 2^nB = f_n
\end{align}
$$
As required.

Comment: Can I ask you how you got the RHS of the equation? Like the 3^{n-1}A...

Comment: We define $f_n$ as $3^nA + 2^nB$.  To get $f_{n-1}$, you just substitute $n-1$ for $n$ to get $f_{n-1} = 3^{n-1}A + 2^{n-1}B$.  It's a similar idea for $n-2$.  From there, we can get that first line by just plugging in the definitions. Does that make sense?

Comment: yes thanks a lot!!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is a *list of numbers*. $f_n$ refers to the $n$-th number in the list, for instance, $f_1$ is the first number, $f_3$ is the third number, and so on. This is called a *sequence*.

You've been given the definition for the sequence
$$f_n=A\ 3^n+B\ 2^n$$

Meaning that the $n$-th number of the sequence is equal to the the result of the calculation on the right (you just plug in $n$). For instance, the first value of the list is $3A+2B$, the second value is $9A+4B$, and so on.

$A$ and $B$ are of course just numbers, and you can see that you're going to get a different list depending on what exactly $A$ and $B$ are. The reason the book doesn't give specific values for $A$ and $B$ is because you're supposed to show that the answer to this specific question is the same no matter what they are.

A recurrence relation for a sequence is where each value of the sequence can be calculated from previous values. For example, I could have a sequence called $S$ where each value is twice the previous value, in other words, $S_{n+1}=2S_n$. You're being asked to show that the recurrence relation:

$$f_n=5f_{n-1}-6f_{n-2}$$

Is true for the sequence $f$.

Well, they've given you the exact formula to calculate any given value of $f$. So just use that to calculate $f_n$, $f_{n-1}$ and $f_{n-2}$, and then check that the above equation is true. See the other answers for details on that part.

Comment: I love you guys!!!! My professor just teaches like we all know what he's talking about, never explaining but just rushing through his lectures. English is also his second language. We have a small class size but still, he races thru, and none of us have any calculus backgrounds... LOL I really appreciate it guys... Everything makes sense now. I am soooo grateful! Honest! So is this learned in Calculus or just discrete math?

Comment: @AntonioMontana Just discrete math. There's no calculus here.